# Loop with condition - Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to achieve a loop with the condition but no luck yet.
Just trying if host name is A then add 1.1.1.1 ip address in commands and
if host name of the device is B then add 2.2.2.2 ip address.

Can you please help.

```
      - name: logs
        ios_command:
           commands:
              - show ip bgp vpnv4 vrf SIG neighbors {{item.ip}} routes
              - show ip bgp vpnv4 vrf SIG neighbors {{item.ip}} advertised-routes
        register: grx_cfg
        when: "item.when"
        with_items:
            - { ip: '1.1.1.1',  when "{{ ansible_host =='A' }}" }
            - { ip: '2.2.2.2',   when "{{ ansible_host =='B' }}" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why looping? As per your question, you need `1.1.1.1` when the host is `A` and `2.2.2.2` when the host is `B`. So perhaps, `if/else` is required??

Something like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    ansible_host: A #flip this to B and get 2.2.2.2
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg:
      - show ip bgp vpnv4 vrf SIG neighbors {{ hostname}} routes
      - show ip bgp vpnv4 vrf SIG neighbors {{ hostname }} advertised-routes
    vars:
      hostname: "{%- if ansible_host == 'A' -%}
                     1.1.1.1
                 {%- elif  ansible_host == 'B' -%}
                     2.2.2.2
                 {%- endif -%}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary

```yaml
    ips:
      A: 1.1.1.1
      B: 2.2.2.2
```

Then, for example, given the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
host_1 ansible_host=A
host_2 ansible_host=B
```

The task below

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          commands:
          - show ... {{ ips[ansible_host] }} routes
          - show ... {{ ips[ansible_host] }} advertised-routes
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [host_1] => 
  msg: |-
    commands:
    - show ... 1.1.1.1 routes
    - show ... 1.1.1.1 advertised-routes
ok: [host_2] => 
  msg: |-
    commands:
    - show ... 2.2.2.2 routes
    - show ... 2.2.2.2 advertised-routes
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    ips:
      A: 1.1.1.1
      B: 2.2.2.2

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          commands:
          - show ... {{ ips[ansible_host] }} routes
          - show ... {{ ips[ansible_host] }} advertised-routes
```