# How to add when or if condition on Ansible Variable

Tags: jenkins, plugins, ansible

It is possible to add when or if condition on Ansible variable?
For example we have 2 jenkins server (server A and server B), we want to apply different plugins version for both of them.

Example:

```
jenkins_plugins:
  - name: plugin-x
    version: "1.1" {"if server == A"}
  - name: plugin-x
    version: "1.5" {"if server == B"}
```

Thanks.

I want to apply different plugins version to different servers.

Comment: Hello @Yami, welcome to Stackoverflow. The answer to the question _It is possible to add when or if condition on Ansible variable?_  is **yes**, you may want to search for the keywords `ansible` and `conditionals`. Also, you may benefit from this article regarding [expectations from questions in this platform](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: An example https://stackoverflow.com/a/74440195/6309601

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the dictionary

```yaml
    jenkins_plugins:
      A:
        - name: plugin-x
          version: 1.1
      B:
        - name: plugin-x
          version: 1.5
```

Use it

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: jenkins_plugins[inventory_hostname]
```

---

**Notes**

1. Given the inventory

```bash
shell> cat hosts
A
B
```

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    jenkins_plugins:
      A:
        - name: plugin-x
          version: 1.1
      B:
        - name: plugin-x
          version: 1.5

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: jenkins_plugins[inventory_hostname]
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [A] => 
  jenkins_plugins[inventory_hostname]:
  - name: plugin-x
    version: 1.1
ok: [B] => 
  jenkins_plugins[inventory_hostname]:
  - name: plugin-x
    version: 1.5

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
A: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
B: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

2. Elegant and clean option is putting the variables into the *group_vars*. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/jenkins_plugins.yml 
jenkins_plugins_dict:
  default:
    - name: plugin-x
      version: 1.0
  A:
    - name: plugin-x
      version: 1.1
  B:
    - name: plugin-x
      version: 1.5

jenkins_plugins: "{{ jenkins_plugins_dict[inventory_hostname]|
                     default(jenkins_plugins_dict.default) }}"
```

Then, given the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
A
B
X
```

The playbook

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: jenkins_plugins
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [B] => 
  jenkins_plugins:
  - name: plugin-x
    version: 1.5
ok: [A] => 
  jenkins_plugins:
  - name: plugin-x
    version: 1.1
ok: [X] => 
  jenkins_plugins:
  - name: plugin-x
    version: 1.0

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
A: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
B: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
X: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Ansible can hold different variables for each of your servers/groups in your inventory out of the box and this can actually be much more powerfull and maintainable than your above condition.

As an illustration of [How to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html), and to go a bit beyond your actual example let's imagine you have a default list of plugins for all jenkins servers and you want to override the version for some of them or add additional ones on specific server.

*(Note: this example will not address removing specific plugins from the default but that is also possible...)*

Here's my example global file structure:

```
.
├── check_plugins_versions.yml
└── inventories
    └── demo
        ├── group_vars
        │   └── jenkins
        │       └── plugins.yml
        ├── hosts.yml
        └── host_vars
            └── server2.jenkins.local
                └── specific_jenkins_plugins.yml
```

The hosts are declared in `inventories/demo/hosts.yml`

```yaml
---
jenkins:
  hosts:
    server1.jenkins.local:
    server2.jenkins.local:
```

As you can see, I declared two host as in your question and placed them in a `jenkins` group. So we can now declare variables for that group inside the `inventories/demo/group_vars/jenkins` directory where I placed the `plugins.yml` file

```yaml
---
# List of plugins to install by default
_default_jenkins_plugins:
  - name: plugin-a
    version: "1.1"
  - name: plugin-b
    version: "2.2"
  - name: plugin-x
    version: "1.1"

# Customize plugin list with specific plugins for host if they exist. For this we
# transform the above default list and the specific one to dicts
# combine them and turn them back into a result list
_d_plug_dict: "{{ _default_jenkins_plugins
  | items2dict(key_name='name', value_name='version') }}"
_s_plug_dict: "{{ _specific_jenkins_plugins | d([])
  | items2dict(key_name='name', value_name='version') }}"

jenkins_plugins: "{{ _d_plug_dict | combine(_s_plug_dict)
  | dict2items(key_name='name', value_name='version') }}"
```

Now we can give a list of specific plugins/versions for `server2.jenkins.local`. I placed those values in `inventories/demo/host_vars/server2.jenkins.local/specific_jenkins_plugins.yml`

```yaml
---
_specific_jenkins_plugins:
  # Override version for plugin-x
  - name: plugin-x
    version: "1.5"
  # Install an additional plugin-z  
  - name: plugin-z
    version: "9.9"
```

Then we have a simple `check_plugins_versions.yml` test playbook to verify that the above is doing the job as expected:

```yaml
---
- hosts: jenkins
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: show computed plugins for each server
      debug:
        var: jenkins_plugins
```

Which gives when called with the relevant inventory

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventories/demo/ check_plugins_versions.yml 

PLAY [jenkins] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [show computed plugins for each server] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server1.jenkins.local] => {
    "jenkins_plugins": [
        {
            "name": "plugin-a",
            "version": "1.1"
        },
        {
            "name": "plugin-b",
            "version": "2.2"
        },
        {
            "name": "plugin-x",
            "version": "1.1"
        }
    ]
}
ok: [server2.jenkins.local] => {
    "jenkins_plugins": [
        {
            "name": "plugin-a",
            "version": "1.1"
        },
        {
            "name": "plugin-b",
            "version": "2.2"
        },
        {
            "name": "plugin-x",
            "version": "1.5"
        },
        {
            "name": "plugin-z",
            "version": "9.9"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
server1.jenkins.local      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
server2.jenkins.local      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```